# pyZ3: Expand let-expressions in smt2 output?

Tags: z3, z3py

I am attempting to 'simplify' some smtlib2 files using the z3 Python API via the following:

1. reading in an SMTLIB2 file
2. applying some tactics & extracting a simplified goal
3. adding the simplified goal to a new solver
4. printing the new solver via `to_smt2()`

I have an odd use case where it would be ideal if the resulting smtlib file did not contain any `let` expressions. Is there a way to expand them via the python API?

Answer (score 0):

Creation of let-expressions are controlled by the pretty-printer. Try something like:

```py
set_option(max_args=10000000, max_lines=1000000, max_depth=10000000, max_visited=1000000)
```

You can play with the actual numbers to find a setting that works for your use case. Essentially, the larger the numbers, the less the sharing/chopping off will be.

Also of importance is the parameter `min_alias_size`. Also try setting that to a large number. (The default is 10, which forces let-expressions.)

Comment: It seems there might be other parameters controlling which expressions get 'lifted':  can _reduce_ the number, but not eliminate them entirely using a min_alias_size/max_width of 4294967295

Comment: Some internal constructs might force the creation of a `let`. Impossible to tell without seeing an actual example if you're running into one of those.